# Mongodb pagination by id revival - is it an anti pattern?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

This type of question has been asked before, and I asked it as well, but I still cant wrap my mind around it.

So, Mongo stores documents in natural order by id (which as far as I understand is physical order written to disk?), and each document (pretty much) has an id greater than last. Great. So, lets assume we have 11 documents in a collection, with each integer representing each id in natural sort order, like `[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11]`. Lets suppose documents are arrays.

Suppose we want to page all of those documents with no other query parameters, in pages of 5.

So we execute and get:

`db.foo.find().limit(5)` - `[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]`

`db.foo.find({'_id': {'$gt': [5]}}).limit(5)` - `[6] [7] [8] [9] [10]`

`db.foo.find({'_id': {'$gt': [10]}}).limit(5)` - `[11]`

So far so good.

This time document `[4]` gets a bunch of stuff appended and grows out of pre allocated size limits, so now our physycal/natural(?) sort order is `[1] [2] [3] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [4]`

So we execute and get:

`db.foo.find().limit(5)` - `[1] [2] [3] [5] [6]`

`db.foo.find({'_id': {'$gt': [6]}}).limit(5)` - `[7] [8] [9] [10] [11]`

`db.foo.find({'_id': {'$gt': [11]}}).limit(5)` - nothing

So in this case we skip `[4]`? Similar thing can happen, in that case, if a document gets deleted and a new one added in its place that would normally become `[12]`. If my understanding is correct - pagination without explicitly specifying ordering is an anti-pattern? And on flip side if you specify ordering, would that not mean you have to still visit every document in a collection and then sort them?

Answer (score -1):

If you sort by a index it doesn't have to visit all documents.

> In MongoDB, sort operations can obtain the sort order by retrieving
>   documents based on the ordering in an index. If the query planner
>   cannot obtain the sort order from an index, it will sort the results
>   in memory. Sort operations that use an index often have better
>   performance than those that do not use an index. In addition, sort
>   operations that do not use an index will abort when they use 32
>   megabytes of memory.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: Welcome! A valid answer requires more than just a link, which become unavailable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer